# Linq and datetime validation

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to insert a DateTime value in sqlserver using linq. The DateTime value in the csharp side may be null. The corresponding field in sqlserver is a nullable datetime field. Following is my code:

```
using (var dataContext = GetDataContext())
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    var combinedWorkBasket = new CombinedWorkBasket()
    {

        FirstName = combinedWorkbasketData.FirstName,
        LastName = combinedWorkbasketData.LastName,
        Address1 = combinedWorkbasketData.Address1,
        RetirementDate = Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate),

    };
    dataContext.CombinedWorkBaskets.InsertOnSubmit(combinedWorkBasket);
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

When combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate happens to be null, which is a string value, which could be a valid date or null, then sqlserver throws error saying the date should be within range. When combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate happens to be null, Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate) translates to some invalide data value. I tried the following, still same issue.

```
RetirementDate = DateTime.TryParse(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate, out temp) ? Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate) : Convert.ToDateTime(null)
```

I simply want to accomplish the following: When combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate is a valid date insert RetirementDate, otherwise don't insert it but insert other values such as Firstname etc

Thanks

Comment: Is RetirementDate Nullable<DateTime> ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a nullable data type, but this helps only if your database permits null values in the RetirementDate column. In addition, you must make the RetirementDate field in class CombinedWorkBasket nullable, too.

```
using (var dataContext = GetDataContext())
{
    DateTime? dateTime;
    var combinedWorkBasket = new CombinedWorkBasket()
    {

        FirstName = combinedWorkbasketData.FirstName,
        LastName = combinedWorkbasketData.LastName,
        Address1 = combinedWorkbasketData.Address1,
        RetirementDate = combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate != null ?
            Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate) : null;

    };
    dataContext.CombinedWorkBaskets.InsertOnSubmit(combinedWorkBasket);
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that datetime does not holds null value but it holds minimum time i.e. some thing like this. '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'.
Instead of directly passing the date time try using

```
DateTime.MinValue== Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate)?Null:Convert.ToDateTime(combinedWorkbasketData.RetirementDate)
```

I have not tested the code use it as reference u might be needing some refinement.

Answer (score 0):

I think RetirementDate must be of nullable type for Entity framework to insert DBNull.

So make it like

```
public class CombinedWorkBasket
{
    // other fields
    public DateTime? RetirementDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then try assigning Null as per logic with associated column as "Allow Null" in database.

Hopefully it will insert null.